# Count UPPERCASE Words in Python

Tags: python, string

I am attempting to count the number of times specific words appear in a text, and also identify how many times those words are all CAPS. It seems to me that the following should return a count of 4 and 1. Instead I get 4 and 2. My [understanding from the docs is that str.isupper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) should only return True if all letters are upper. What am I misunderstanding?

If there's a better overall approach, I'm open to that too.

Thanks.

```
text = "happy HAPPY Joy joy."
hw_count = 0
hcw_count = 0
happy_words = re.compile('happy|joy|love', re.IGNORECASE)
hw_count = happy_words.findall(text)
if len(hw_count) > 0 :
    print("Happy word count:", len(hw_count))
for word in hw_count :
    if word[0].isupper() :
         hcw_count = hcw_count + 1
print("Happy CAP word count:", hcw_count)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check `word[0].isupper()` instead of `word.isupper()`. In other words, you only check if the first letter is capitalized. This makes `Happy` a false-positive.

Comment: Argh! I thought [0] was accessing the first element in the array, meaning each word. Not each letter. Thanks.